# Multi language lable changes in the .xib file.

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, xib, nslocalizedstring

I have to develop the application into Four(4) languages (English, French, Italic, Spanish).

So, for that I want to know is there any way to display different language data using only one(1) `.xib file` in the top bar.

**Example:**

> I have the Setting.xib (.xib file) in
>   which there are four labels in the
>   view part and in the top bar of that
>   Nib file I want to change the label
>   names according to the set language
>   using One & Only one Nib file.

So, please give me the appropriate solution.

Which will take less time for the loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why you can't simply use `NSLocalizedString` when setting the label text, it does exactly what you want, loading the appropriate version of the text, according to the device's language.

Anyway, I think you could find something useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726215/855738).

I actually did something similar, with six languages and only a single Nib but in my case I could have had the language changed inside the app, so I needed to be able to forcefully tell it to load me the localized version of a string from the specific bundle.

Here's the exact code that should help you in case your problem is more like mine and a simple NSLocalizedString is not enough:

```
NSString* path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"];

NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

someLabel.text = [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:@"textKey" value:@"" table:nil];
```

Since you will probably have more than one label, it would be a good idea to have the path stored as a class property and set in viewDidLoad, so you will be able to access it from any method/function inside that class.