# How to change language setting of MPMediaPickerController.

Tags: ios, iphone, multilingual, ibaction, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm creating a music App and I want to support multi languages of `MPMediaPickerController`.
I programmed as follows:

```
- (IBAction)pushedMusicButton:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *pickerController = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    pickerController.accessibilityLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Language setting = %@", pickerController.accessibilityLanguage);
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I ran this code on my iPhone whose setting is Japanese.

MediaPicker window opened but the string of the button is English… like 'Playlists', 'Artists' or 'Songs'. 
Log showed accessibilityLanguage is set to JP (Language setting = ja).

How can I change language setting of MPMediaPickerController?

**Environment:** XCode 4.4.1, iOS SDK 5.1, iPhone (iOS 5.1)

Comment: check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974680/multi-language-lable-changes-in-the-nib-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sun Tzu and venkat, I finally found the localized **file** is really needed.  but the localized **string** doesn't.

I created `Localizable.string` files in `en.lproj` and `ja.lproj` and added them to my project.  At first I tried to build with null (0byte) `Localizable.string` but there was a build error, so I entered one set of strings.
In *en.lproj*:

```
"Playlists" = "Playlists";
```

In *ja.lproj*:

[image]

Then, not only 'Playlists' but also other label ('Artists', 'Songs',..) was displayed in Japanese.

[image]

For the confirmation, I changed the setting to Deutsch.  but it displayed as 'Songs' in English. (Not 'Titel')

[image]

I created de.lproj folder and copied Localizable.string which is completely same as en.lproj's one. Finally 'Titel' comes.

[image]

So, the labels in MPMediaPickerController speaks your mother language, when you added Localizable.string file in .lproj.

My code snippet is:

```
- (IBAction)pushedMusicButton:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *pickerController = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```